# Route groups and form posting in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am using CoreUI and Laravel to build a project and I want to make a form on clients/addclient which will pass all the data from form to my database.

I am struggling into this part:

I have these routes on web.php:

```
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'clients'], function(){
    Route::get('addclient', 'ClientController@index');
    Route::post('submit','ClientController@save');
    Route::get('viewclient', function () { return view('pages.clients.viewclient'); });
    Route::get('products', function () { return view('pages.clients.products'); });
});
```

I have a file called addclient.blade.php with this form tag:

```
<form action="{{url('clients/submit')}}" method="POST">
```

and on ClientController I have made this function just for testing that I get the data back:

```
function save(Request $req){
    print_r($req->input());
}
```

what am I doing wrong and I dont see any results?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'clients'], function(){
    Route::get('addclient', 'ClientController@index')->name('addclient');
    Route::post('submit','ClientController@save')->name('submit');
    Route::get('viewclient', function () { return view('pages.clients.viewclient'); });
    Route::get('products', function () { return view('pages.clients.products'); });
});
```

in form

```
<form action="{{route('clients.submit')}}" method="POST">
```

you can see list group route :

```
php artisan route:list
```

Comment: i get this error now: Route [clients.submit] not defined. (View: C:\Users\ANM\Documents\GitHub\WSPanel\resources\views\pages\clients\addclient.blade.php)

Comment: run this command php artisan route:list to see all routes

Comment: I see it on the list but its still the same message and i tried to clear the cache